# Internet issues after upgrading to 22.10

Tags: networking, 22.10

After upgrading to 22.10, my WiFi is not worling properly. I am using a MacBook Pro, with a Broadcom device..
LAN works fine, i can ping other devices on my home network, I can remote control the MacBook from a windows computer and I can ping 8.8.8.8, but can't access the internet and it seems like the network-manager service is missing..
This worked fine in 22.04.

Please help!

Update:
Output from terminal:

```
    lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: What do you mean by "WAN"? Is it Wi-FI? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I have updated my question with output

Comment: If you can ping 8.8.8.8 then networking itself is probably fine. However, it might be DNS which is failing.

Can you check the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` and share with us?

Comment: Probably.. running that command yields "cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it!
/etc/resolv.conf was corrupt or something..
I did

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

then I created a new resolv.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and added the line

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

after that I reconnected to my WiFi and I am back in the game

Thank you for taking the time to hep me out! :)

Answer (score 0):

A wrong driver is installed.

Run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: This didn't work.. sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer requires a connection but even wired ethernet doesn't connect to the internet..

Comment: Use a phone to get an internet connection.

Comment: Doesn't work either... probably something wrong with dns-configuration